# ¿Cuál es la función que emula la funcionalidad de bindParam y bindValue en la extensión MySQL Legacy?

Tags: mysql

Mysql_bind_in_out con una combinación adecuada de parámetros.

No existe equivalente.

Mysql_bind_param y mysql_bind_value.

Comment: Estás preguntando o afirmando ?

Comment: @Betam preguntando